# Eclipse RCP editor docking behaviour for views

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In an Eclipse RCP application I would like to create a View that contains multiple child views, allowing docking only within the enclosing view.

The behaviour I'm looking for is the same as the Java Editor allows in the Eclipse IDE. i.e. you can split the Java editor up and drag and drop Java files between the split sections. However, you can't drop a Java file outside the enclosing editor.

So in effect, it is kind of like a mini perspective allowing a pre-defined set of views to be docked within it.

Does anyone know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the default presentation. You may have to implement your own presentation and do this stuff.